# using "precursor" classes in collections

Tags: java, generics

I have a method

```
<T> void f (Collection<T> c, T t)
```

Alas, sometimes I need to pass as the first arg not **Collection** but **Collection<P>** where **P** is a *precursor* for **T**, i.e., there is a **P** *getter* method returning a **T**.
So how do I modify my method to work with both **Collection<P>** and **Collection<T>** (in the  latter case the *getter* is the identity)?

E.g.,

```
<T> boolean f (Collection<T> c, T t) {
  for (T x : c) if (x.equals(t)) return true;
  return false;
}
class Z { String a, b; }
```

I want to be able to use **f** to search **Collection<Z>** by either **a** or **b**:

```
f(Collection<Z> c1 ???searching by a???, "foo")
f(Collection<Z> c2 ???searching by b???, "bar")
```

I have *no* control over the implementation of **T** and **P**; in particular, I cannot make **P** inherit from **T** (and I don't want to: as in **Z** above, I might want to search by different fields at different times).

I do *not* want to create an intermediate **Collection<T>** by mapping.

I want something like the [common **:key** Lisp keyword argument](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_reduce.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using something like a interface for the predicate to check on equality. An example would be:

```
interface Predicate<T> {
     public boolean test(T element);
}
```

and then use the following function:

```
 public <T> boolean f(Collection<T> c, Predicate<T> p) {
     for (T x : c) if (p.test(x)) return true;
     return false;
 }
```

Then you could call it the following ways:

```
Collection<T> ts;
f(ts, new Predicate<T> () { 
            public boolean test(T element) { 
                      return element.equals("foo"); 
            }
 });

Collection<P> ps;
f(ps, new Predicate<P> () { 
            public boolean test(P element) { 
                      return element.getT().equals("foo"); 
            }
});
```

While this syntax is quite verbose it should fit your question. It will however get prettier in Java 8 when lambda functions will arrive.

Comment: Even better, you can use equals() instead of another method name

Comment: @sds See also Guava functional features - seems they've already implemented this (http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained)

Comment: @sds This idiom is from functional languages, and is often known as any or exists.

Answer (score -1):

Given that "Holder" is the precursor class and "Stuff" is the gotten class, you can do this:

EDIT: Switched to messy instanceof statements.

```
public <H, T> boolean contains (Collection<H> c, T t) {
  if (c instanceof Collection<T>)
  {
    for (T x : c) if (x.equals(t)) return true;
    return false;
  }
  //else
  for (H x : c) if (x.getStuff().equals(t)) return true;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: This wont compile. Both methods have the same type erasure.

Comment: this requires control over the definitions of T and H which I lack.

Comment: Wait, do the Holders have a standard way to get the Stuff? As in, they implement a StuffGetter interface?

Comment: He don't have _no control over the implementation of `T` and `P`_

Comment: This still wont compile because of type erasure :-/ You cannot use `instanceof` with a generic type.